# Angular external API call keeps serving on poort 4200 after adding proxy configuration

Tags: angular, api, proxy

[image]I have made all the necessary proxy configuration but my Angular still serve to 4200 where i get 404 error. What am i doing wrong?

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "info"
  },
  "pathRewrite": {
    "^/api": ""
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
}
```

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: '/api'
};
```

**Service.ts**

```
fetchData() {
    return this.http
      .get<any[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/registration`)
      .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, i had to provide only the endpoint of my request. So it should be like:

```
fetchData() {
    return this.http
      .get<any[]>(`/registration`)
      .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
  }
```